# Swiper.js Loop: true not working when slidesPerView and slidesPerColumn set

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

When using the very popular swiper.js, normally works as expected. However currently loop = true is not working because we have slidesPerView and slidesPerColumn enabled.

Currently have:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('#my-swiper', {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  slidesPerColumn: 2,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  speed: 2000,
  loop: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 1000,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
```

Several others have ran into a similar issue but not clear solution. One noted they added to help resolve the issue:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    mySwiper.update(true);
    mySwiper.slideTo(0, 0)
}, 100);
```

Tried adding after the above code block but they there is no motion at all. If I added it inside the above code block then it shows one large thumbnail per slide vs 6. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer has confirmed currently slidesPerColumn is not compatible with looping which is why it breaks. Hopefully this will be fixed soon. In the meantime, my workaround is have to instances to simulate 2 rows. Not ideal for a couple reasons but the end result for the user at least is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 with Swiper v8.4.2 :

-> set a number of slides per view by default,
otherwise Swiper fail to enable infinite loop

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <!-- swiper-slides ... -->
  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="..." alt="..."/>
  </div>
  <!-- ... swiper-slides -->
</div>
```

my config Swiper :

```
  var init_Swiper = new Swiper('#related_prods',{

        // Swiper options :
        direction : 'horizontal',
        // set a number of slides per view by default
        // otherwise Swiper fail to enable infinite loop
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 16,
        centerInsufficientSlides : true,
        centeredSlidesBounds : true,
        loop: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        grabCursor: true,
        mousewheel: false,
        breakpoints: {
          1024: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 16,
          },
          767: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 16,
          },
          0 : {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 10,
          }
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-related_products-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-related_products-prev",
          },
  });
```

Comment: After mores tests : Not work properly if your slides are < than slidesPerView number ...